# Sending email with a CSV attachment via PHPMailer

Tags: php, csv, phpmailer, email-attachments

I tried sending email that had a CSV file attachment with PHPmailer. Something seems to be wrong because the code gives me an error notice. I downloaded the PHPmailer from GitHub and extracted it via FTP to my server. Then I used the following code but as I told you it doesn't work. What seems to be the problem?

```
// EMAIL SENDING SCRIPT

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->SetFrom('tuomas.viikeri@totaali.com', 'EXK-verkkosovellus');
$email->Subject   = 'Uusi tilaus';
$email->Body      = '<h1>Tässä tilaus EXK-verkkosovelluksen kautta</h1>';
$email->AddAddress( 'tuomas.viikeri@gmail.com' );

$file_to_attach = '/testing/file.csv';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'file.csv' );
return $email->Send();

header('Location: /testing/kiitos.html');
```

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: The error is HTTP ERROR 500, but I don't really know how to debug PHP, cause I'm kind of novice with PHP still.

Comment: Please add this line -  ini_set("display_errors",1);   in top of your script. Then run your script you can get errors

Comment: Probably you are missing some SMTP settings (or others).. In general I mean some e-mail settings, where should be the mail send from.

Comment: why did you use header statement after return

Comment: The error is: `Warning: require(testing/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u41044/public_html/testing/form-handle.php on line 130 Warning: require(testing/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u41044/public_html/testing/form-handle.php on line 130 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'testing/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php' (include_path='.:') in /home/u41044/public_html/testing/form-handle.php on line 130`

Comment: @AnishChandran i want to direct the user to a thank you page. I guess that is not how to do it then cause there is the return?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was with

```
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
```

I just needed to change path/to part to correct one.

Comment: if($email->Send()) { header('Location: /testing/kiitos.html');} else { header('Location: error page');}

Comment: It's also a good idea to check return values from calls to things like `addAttachment` and `send`, which tell you if they succeeded, and inspect `ErrorInfo` for clues when you have problems.